# I am having problem with hibernate. I have ubuntu 20.04LTS and it doesn't hibernates

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, hibernation

When i do sudo hibernate, it gives me this error :

```
hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found.
Some modules failed to unload: nvidia_drm nvidia_modeset nvidia
hibernate: Aborting suspend due to errors in ModulesUnloadBlacklist (use --force to override).
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue and after some testing I was able to go to hibernate on Ubuntu 20.04.2.

conclusions:

1. hibernate won't work with Nvidia's On-demand prime profile, but works with **Performance** or **Intel** profile
2. works fine with **pm-hibernate** from pm-utils package (sudo apt install pm-utils)

Answer (score 0):

Check if nvidia driver is installed properly or not using : $nvidia-smi

If its not purge nvidia drivers & re-install properly.
OR purge nvidia drivers & xorg. Re-install xorg using $sudo apt install xorg

& try your command : $sudo hibernate